# How do I upload images in a CRUD App via LARAVEL?

Tags: laravel, crud, laravel-7

I have a problem with my Laravel CRUD App. It's about a simple examplary contact datatable. Everything goes fine until I try to upload some images. My index view shows only the broken image. I've already checked the path and although I've set the path the same (except for the file name of course) it shows complete random paths at times. Ironically this isn't the case for the last image of the table. In the final row it shows the image as intended and I don't know why.

Here's my code for the file upload (Well, the whole store function for that matter):

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'first_name'=>'required',
            'last_name'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required | email',
            'picture'=>'max:2048'
        ]);

        $contact = new Contact([
            'first_name' => $request->get('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $request->get('last_name'),
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'job_title' => $request->get('job_title'),
            'city' => $request->get('city'),
            'country' => $request->get('country'),
            'picture' => $request->file('picture')

        ]);
        if ($files = $request->file('picture')) {
        $destinationPath = 'public/image/'; // upload path
        $profileImage = $files->getClientOriginalName();
        $files->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
        $insert['picture'] = "$profileImage";
    }
        $contact->save();
        return redirect('/contacts')->with('success', 'Contact saved!');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'first_name'=>'required',
            'last_name'=>'required',
            'email'=>'required | email',
            'picture'=>'max:2048'
        ]);

        $contact = new Contact;
        $contact->first_name = $request->first_name;
        $contact->last_name = $request->last_name;
        $contact->job_title = $request->job_title;
        $contact->country = $request->country;
        if ($request->hasFile('picture')) {
          $filename = $request->file('picture')->getClientOriginalName();//get image original name
          $image_path = $request->file('picture')->move(public_path('image/'), $filename);//image save in public/image folder
          $contact->picture = $filename;
        }
        $contact->save();
        return redirect('/contacts')->with('success', 'Contact saved!');
    }
}
```

Call image path in your view `src="{{asset('/image/'.$your_contact_image )}}"`

```
<img src="{{asset('/image/.$your_contact_image')}}" height="50" width="50" style="float: left">
```